# solaris filemerge and pstack equivalents for linux

Tags: linux, merge, solaris, filemerge

Accepting the possibility of extreme ridicule, I must admit that I really miss sun Teamware's filemerge tool. I have switched from solaris to red hat linux, and find myself regularly missing filemerge (not to be confused with the Apple tool of the same name), as well as the solaris version of pstack (which worked on core files just as well as pids).

Do any experts out there have any advice of consolation? Better merging tools that incorporate ancestry? A single-line way to view the call stack of a core file?

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gdb -ex bt program_file core_file should print out the stack trace of the core file.

As for filemrege, there's a bunch of open source stuff:

tkdiff
meld
mgdiff
kdiff3

Answer (score 1):

meld is great

Answer (score 1):

I use kdiff3 instead of filemerge. kdiff3 can resolve conflicts much better that filemerge.

Usage:

```
kdiff3 x.A.cpp x.C.cpp x.P.cpp -o x.M.cpp
```

where:

```
x.A.cpp - ancestor version of x.cpp
x.C.cpp - child verion of x.cpp
x.P.cpp - parent version of x.cpp
x.M.cpp - merged file
```

These files are produced after you run the resolve command.